# Can you override the stream writers in scala @serializable objects?

Tags: serialization, scala, serializable

I now understand that scala @serializable objects can be used the same as a Java Serializable object.  In a Java Serializable object there are methods you can override to change how the object streams:  writeObject(ObjectOutputStream) / readObject(ObjectOutputStream).

Can you override or inject methods into a scala @serializable object allowing you to change how the object serializes?

Comment: Thanks!  I was getting the signature of the method wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same methods in Scala as in Java:

```
@throws(classOf[IOException])
private def writeObject(out: ObjectOutputStream): Unit = // ...

@throws(classOf[IOException])
private def readObject(in: ObjectInputStream): Unit = // ...
```

Comment: readObject returns Unit.  What is an example implementation that makes an object?  Given that it is a method on the instance?  The examples in java all call this.someProperty to assign values.  How does this work in scala with immutable vals on case classes?

Comment: @ScottSmith I suspect you're stuck using mutable fields or some really nasty reflection tricks.

Comment: @ScottSmith ... or maybe employ the [writeReplace and readResolve](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) methods.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated, you can define your own writeObject and readObject methods.

```
@throws(classOf[java.io.IOException])
private def writeObject(out : java.io.ObjectOutputStream) : Unit = /* your definition  here */
```

However be careful when performing this on nested classes, objects or traits.

@serializable
class Foo(x : Int) {
   @serializable object X { def y = x }
}

If I serialize object X, it will actually serialize the containing Foo class, so this must also be serializable.   This can be a PITA to deal with in custom serialization methods, so here's fair warning.

Another pain-point can be closure serialization.  Try to keep a mental model of what variables are being captured in serialized closures.   Ensure that these variables are something you'd want sent over IO!